# How to set default style for libreOffice Object Formula?

Tags: libreoffice

When I insert a formula, I have to anchor it to paragraph. I would like to do it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type "fn" in the beginning of the paragraph + press {F3} and you will have everything formatted like a charm.